# Not able to start Service using Broadcast Receivers

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to start a  service using BroadcastReceiver with this code

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context,BlueToothService.class);   

    context.startService(myIntent);

}
```

But not able to start the service.
I also registered service and receiver in manifest.

And I have also one doubt, can we use Broadcast Receiver without activity?

This is my service class

```
public class BlueToothService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onStartCommand(Intent intent, int startId) {

    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Toast.makeText(this, "service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    doBluetoothJob();

}
```

My manifest file looks like this.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </application>

    <service
        android:name=".BlueToothService"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </service>

    <receiver android:name="com.simsys.bt.DemoBT" >
    </receiver>

    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: How do you say that the service is not started? And yes - you can use `BroadcastReceiver` without `Activity`. For example, you can register a receiver in a `Service`, or as you have already done, you can register it in manifest.

Comment: Your question doesn't given too many details. What do you mean by "not working" - is the broadcast not being called? Is the service not being called? do you see some error? who calls the broadcast receiver?

Comment: Ok.. this is my service class...

Comment: No.. but not able to see Toast and the service is not visible in devices running service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is working with me i created a Receiver.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(context, "MyReceiver Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent myIntent=new Intent(context,MyService.class);        
        context.startService(myIntent);
    }
}
```

---

then create a Simple Service

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {      
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

---

don't forget to make Entry for Broadcast Receiver and service in manifest file

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">        
<service
    android:enabled="true"
    android:name=".MyService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name = "com.rdc.MyService">
        </action>
    </intent-filter>
  </service>
  <receiver
    android:enabled="true"
    android:name=".MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
</application>
```

now after reboot the emulator Toast will appear.

Comment: Hi Ramdhan I did the same without activity. but it seems to be not working.

Comment: @MrNice Okay! check here i have uploaded sample code http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/03/start-service-from-broadcast-receiver.html

Comment: @ Ramdhan Choudhary.. pls run your code in emulator and see In Enmulator Running Services it is not showing.

Comment: @MrNice just now i downloaded that code and executed its working fine with my 2.2 sdk Emulator, don't know where you going wrong, just import the project into eclipse and run then close and restart the Emulator, you will get Toast "Service Started" after unlocking screen, you can also put Log with Toast, so you can get message in log-cat, still if you getting trouble let me know i'll mail you sample code.

Answer (score 1):

The manifest file you posted is incorrectly formulated. The `<service>` and `<receiver>` tags need to be **inside** the `<application>` tag. Like this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <service
        android:name=".BlueToothService"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </service>
    <receiver android:name="com.simsys.bt.DemoBT" >
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: Hello @David Wasser i did that still i am not able to see the toast.

Comment: Interesting. Are you doing this on a real device? What is the device? At this point, since none of the many suggestions seem to be of any help to you, you should probably post your current code, your current manifest and any logcat that may be useful.

Comment: Thanks Mr David Wasser.. now it is working. Sorry i forget to put Action Tag in Receiver.

Comment: That's terrific. Glad to be of help.

Comment: @MrNice I have a same problem. Can you clarify me what do you mean by Action tag and how it helped you to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override [onStartCommand()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) not onStart() in your Service subclass. onStart() is depreciated, it should still be called but it would be recommended to override onStartCommand() and see if that works.

Additionally, in your manifest file the service, receiver and intent-filter tags should be children of the application tag. The receiver also needs to declare what intents it will process. e.g.

```
<receiver android:name="com.simsys.bt.DemoBT" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.simsys.bt.intents.StartService" />
    </intent-filter>    
</receiver>
```

Comment: Yes.. Mr Charles Harley.But it is also not showing the toast.

Comment: Could you also post the part of your manifest that declares the service?

Comment: Have you correctly matched the signature of onStartCommand()? See the docs I linked to in my answer for the correct set of parameters and return value to match.

Answer (score 0):

Try showing your toast with:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And you need to give the service declaration in the manifest an specific intentfilter with the intent you want it to listen to like:

```
<receiver android:name="com.simsys.bt.DemoBT" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="your.intent.action.definition" />
    </intent-filter>    
</receiver>
```